# Key input lag on Chrome Browser in Trusty

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, google-chrome

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and am experiencing great difficulty in typing in Google Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94 (64-bit). Typing works normally in gedit, emacs, etc but in my browser it is really slowly and often prone to typing the characters slightly out of order. It is extremely frustrating and I haven't been able to Google for a solution yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Close voters: Where is this Chrome bug? The problem could be caused by a Chrome extension.

Comment: What is a "close voter"? Any idea why I was down voted on this question?

Comment: There are reviewers of your question "close voters" who have the opinion that your problem is because of a bug, which it clearly isn't as you said in your answer. The only other opinion I was able to find is that your question is unclear which it also isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I resolved the issue by enabling the proprietary NVIDEA drivers and restarting my computer. The open source ones were not allowing Chrome to do proper graphics